# Android - proper place to put my Sqlite3 database in Eclipse?

Tags: android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

This guy talks about the android system path:

> //The Android's default system path of your application database.
>   private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE/databases/";

and here: DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.android.example/databases/" in many other links regarding sqlite databases.

Problem is, is that eclipse(on mac osx 10.7) didnt create a data directory and on my motorola xoom(which has Android 4.0.3 - ice cream sandwich) i am unable to determine what its default system path is. I dont see anything referring to /data/data/... using the Astro file manager.

Since i am on using a mac i have had to use the android file system app to transfer my apk files from my eclipse workspace onto the motorola xoom. I supposed one of my questions should be - where would be the proper place to put this or does is matter?

i downloaded the Sqlite database browser already and filled up my database as the link above talks about. i dont have any primary keys. i have copied the .db file into my assets folder in my project - also as the link states.

Also since my database is already created with tables really all i need to do (i guess) is copy the tables to that data directory that everyone always mentions and then i should be able to do inserts/updates/selects, etc etc?

my code so far:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private Context myDbContext;
private static String dbName = "restaurant";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context){
    super(context, dbName, null, 1);
    this.myDbContext = context;

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

      //need to take input from local database and copy it 
      //but where do i copy the information to? what path should i use?

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.w(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(), "upgrading database/changing database which will remove all old data!");
    db.execSQL("drop table if exists menu");
    db.execSQL("drop table if exists items");
    db.execSQL("drop table if exists server");
    onCreate(db);
}
```

}

Comment: i will comment real quickly. i understand that you need to take the database from the apk and copy the contents on my xoom so that i can do my queries. the question is is can i just make up my own place to store it or does it have to be in a certain path on the system?

Answer (score 0):

> Problem is, is that eclipse(on mac osx 10.7) didnt create a data directory

Eclipse does not create a `/data` directory on a device. It is there from the factory.

> and on my motorola xoom(which has Android 4.0.3 - ice cream sandwich) i am unable to determine what its default system path is.

There is no concept in Android of a "default system path".

> Since i am on using a mac i have had to use the android file system app to transfer my apk files from my eclipse workspace onto the motorola xoom.

Most Android developers simply run the app from Eclipse.

> Also since my database is already created with tables really all i need to do (i guess) is copy the tables to that data directory that everyone always mentions and then i should be able to do inserts/updates/selects, etc etc?

Use [`SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper), which gives you instructions for packaging the database in Eclipse and will then unpack it for you in the proper spot at runtime.